# var undefined when using EJS with express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, passport.js, passport-local

I am using EJS as view engine for an express app, I am having the following issue: Whenever I want to use a variable on EJS, I got an error telling me that that variable is not defined, in order to solve this, I have to put `locals` before the variable, I don't know if this is some config problem or what, but I have been trying to look for an answer and haven't got one yet. The funny-sad thing, is that after I use the `locals` stuff, I can render the ejs with no problem, but the expected output does not appear, so I am not getting render erros, but I my variables aren't showing up neither.

Some of my code:

```
//app.js
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
//...
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.use(expressLayouts);
...


//layouts.ejs
        <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
          <% if(locals.user){%>   //-> As you may see here, If I dont use locals before user, I got the 'user' is undefined
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
            <% }else{ %>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/users/login">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/users/register">Register</a>
              </li>
              <% } %>
        </ul>


//register.ejs
<h2 class="page-header">Register</h2>
<% if(locals.errors){ %>
    <% errors.forEach(function(err){ %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>
        <%=err.msg%>
        </p>
        </div>
        <% });%>
<%}%>
```

So I don't know if this is a issue from my ejs config, or from my way of passing the variables from the controller.

Comment: I think you should check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgAseumFyg8&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_&index=19&t=279s) out.

Comment: How are you passing `user` to the template? That would be the most likely cause of the problem.

Comment: If the user log ins correctly, passport should pass me the `user` object. There is a line that has `done(null,user)` when the user logs in correctly, so I asume I can call user from the view. Also, I discovered I don't have to use `locals` anymore, as I declared it as a global variable, anyway It looks that the user functions is not being passed to the view.

Comment: You need to pass it yourself, e.g. `res.render('register', {user: user});`. Alternatively you could set it using `res.locals.user = user`.